# Getting module not callable when trying to run package installed from setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, site-packages

I have this whole case on GitHub https://github.com/jiri-otoupal/dievpn.

It normally works, when I just run it through `main.py`
But if i install it with `python setup.py install` and try to run dvpn

It throws exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Projects\dvpn\venv\Scripts\dvpn-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('dvpn==0.5.3', 'console_scripts', 'dvpn')())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I had looked at it closely but can not find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is problem with `if __name__ == "__main__"` not executing as an entrypoint, function to entrypoint needed to be passed in `setup.py` with `module=module.submod:func`.